# cannot listen to interfaces without root privilege

Tags: networking, virtualbox, wireshark

for certain reason, I wanted to capture traffic without being root.

**Setup**:

```
Host： Ubuntu 3.11.0
Guest Ubuntu 3.13.0
Wireshark in Guest:1.10.8
```

I have done this trying to enable capturing without root

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common 
$ sudo usermod -a -G wireshark $USER
$ gnome-session-quit --logout --no-prompt
```

and it indeed add my user account to the wireshark group. Still I am not able to capture the traffic. No interface is shown

**---UPDATE----**

I retried it on my host, and it succeeds, however it doesn't succeed in my guest machine. Some observation I had which might be relevant is that in host, I got group `wireshark` by issuing `sudo groups`, while in guest, there's no group `wireshark` observed by issuing `sudo groups`. So I guess there's something wrong with adding group wireshark to my guest machine

Comment: is libcap2-bin installed, and have you configured dumpcap as described here: http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/mar/19/sniffing-wireshark-non-root-user/ ?

Comment: hadn't set dumpcap before, but now reset it according to the link. Still nothing happened